# Generating function values in java

Tags: java, function

I am trying to generate N random x values to pass to a charting component. The only concern is that they need to be sorted. I was wondering whether there is any better way than generating N points, sorting them, and then generating values for each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate the points with random and use Arrays.sort() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use generated random value as a delta for previous value, like this

```
x[i] = x[i-1] + random.nextInt();
```

(or minus delta, depending on sorting direction)

For limiting delta, modulo operator can be used, of course.